# Is it possible to change the Jitsi share url without hosting jitsi on a private server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jitsi, video-conferencing

I have integrated jitsi in my react app using this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jutsu). Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Jutsu } from "react-jutsu";

const App = () => {
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [call, setCall] = useState(false);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (room && name) setCall(true);
  };

  return call ? (
    <div>
      <h6>LoDeep Room created by host</h6>
      <Jutsu
        roomName={room}
        displayName={name}
        password={password}
        onMeetingEnd={() => console.log("Meeting has ended")}
        loadingComponent={<p>loading ...</p>}
        errorComponent={<p>Oops, something went wrong</p>}
      />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <form>
      <input
        id="room"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Room"
        value={room}
        onChange={(e) => setRoom(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        id="name"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        id="password"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Password (optional)"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="submit">
        Start / Join
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

 
export default App;
```

This seamlessly integrates Jitsi in the app by using the Jitsi public server.
The problem with this approach is that users who are not logged-in in my app may be able to access those jitsi rooms if the user who is logged-in shares the public jitsi room link with them. For example:

> https://meet.jit.si/Sami

I would like to prevent the users who are not connected to my app from accessing the Jitsi rooms inside my app.

Do I have to host Jitsi in a private server in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement JWT for user authentication for accessing your meeting instance.

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/tokens.md) & you may take a look at a [setup guide](https://community.jitsi.org/t/jwt-tokens-install-guide/53359/11) from Jitsi community.